# Changing Array Value

Tags: c++, arrays

I was wondering if someone could lead me in the right direction of how to change a value in an array list if it satisfy a condition in the program.

What I mean is I  want to only roll a dice if the user doesn't want to keep that value of the dice.

So I created this function to roll a dice:

```
int roll[numDice];

for(int i = 0; i <= numDice; i++){
    roll[i] = rand()%6+1;
}
```

Which will give me random numbers for however many dices are in the program.

So now I asked the user to keep the most common number (to make a Yahtzee).

So I did a string of if else like:

```
if (usersKeep == roll[1]){
     cout << "we will keep this dice 1";
}
```

So I want to in this function keep this value (not have it rolled) then in an another else roll the rest of the dice. However I do not know the logic behind changing the value of the other dice or keeping the dice.

Comment: `i <= numDice` is 100% wrong, and causing undefined behavior for your program.

Comment: Also, unless `numDice` is a compile time constant, your code relies on compiler extensions. It is not pure C++.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be testing the value of the array element, you should be testing the index (because they might have the same roll on multiple dice). Then just use an `if/else`

```
if (usersKeep == i) {
    cout << "We will keep this die " << i << '\n';
} else {
    cout << "Rolling die " << i << '\n';
    roll[i] = rand() % 6 + 1;
}
```

Note that this `usersKeep` variable only allows them to keep one die, but Yahtzee allows you to select multiple dice to keep. You can use a `std::set<int>` to hold the list, and test if `i` is a member of the set.

Answer (score 0):

If it really is for a yahtzee, you have a fixed number of dice, 5 if I remember well. You then need 5 int.

But as a way to flag if the dice is to be kept or not you could use a structure.

```
typedef struct dice {
    int value;
    int keep;
}    dice;
```

Then have a dice array.

```
dice dices[5];
```

Set the `dices[n].keep = 0` at first
Then add a condition in your loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (roll[i].keep == 1) {
        roll[i].value = rand()%6+1;
    }
}
```

And when the user decides to keep a dice

```
if (...) //depends on how you want to ask the user
    dices[i].keep = 1;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `typedef struct dice { ... } dice;` is unnecessary in C++. `struct dice { ... };` is sufficient. You can think of it as `struct` as being automatically `typedef`ed.

Comment: Anyway, there isn't much point to the structure. Yatzee doesn't care about the ordering of the dice, so tracking which die has been kept is a needless complication. All you need is an array of `int` to record the values kept and an `int` to record how many dice have been kept.

Comment: Oh thank you, I always did the structures the C way.

In my opinion it is easier to use a structure array like I did than having to move around values or worse, reallocate an int array.

But there are many ways to go about every problem