# (Homework) Trying to make a Yahtzee game in C++

Tags: c++

I'm in a beginner C++ class and I'm trying to build a Yahtzee game in which the user rolls the dice in hopes to get all five dice the same number. We need to try to hold the dice in which pops up the most (ex. We roll a "4 5 3 3 1", I want to hold a three so it stays constant throughout the game) Then roll again to keep trying to get all five dice the same. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void choiceRoll(){
int num;
int dice1 = rand()%6+1;
int dice2 = rand()%6+1;
int dice3 = rand()%6+1;
int dice4 = rand()%6+1;
int dice5 = rand()%6+1;
cout << "Your roll is: " << dice1 << " " << dice2 << " " << dice3 
<< " " << dice4 << " " << dice5 << endl;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int dice1 = rand()%6+1;
    int dice2 = rand()%6+1;
    int dice3 = rand()%6+1;
    int dice4 = rand()%6+1;
    int dice5 = rand()%6+1;
    int x;
    int num;
    char play;

    cout << "Let's play some Yahtzee!" << endl;
    choiceRoll();
    while(x<1){
        cout << "Which number do you want to hold?";
        cin >> num;
        if (num>=1  and num<=6)
            choiceRoll();
    else{
        cout << "Thanks for playing!";
    }
}
    if (dice1=dice2=dice3=dice4=dice5){
        cout << "YAHTZEE!!!!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Can anyone help me to be able to allow user input to hold a certain number and be able to continue rolling until all numbers are the same?

Comment: `if (dice1=dice2=dice3=dice4=dice5){` is  wrong for multiple reasons.

Comment: Think I helped someone working on the same problem
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896207/changing-array-value/46896560?noredirect=1#comment80741182_46896560)

You guys should get in touch

Comment: What is your actual question? [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: also lookup arrays std::vector and conditions in cpp on google, and read more stackoverflow questions

Comment: BTW, the variables in `choiceRoll` are different from those in `main()`.  The `main()` function can't access the variables in `choiceRoll()`.

Comment: You should store your die in a `std::array`, it will make it much easier to write small functions that act on all of them, it'll also make the values easy to pass around by ref or by value.

Comment: Remember: 1 '=' for assignment, 2 for compare.

Comment: Also remember that `dice1` in `choiceRoll` is not the same variable as `dice1` in `main`.

Answer (score 4):

I was inspired to play with some c++17 freshness. Here goes:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09a24ea78a26f4a4)</kbd>** ¹

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std;

using Score = size_t;

namespace {
    enum class face : Score { one=1, two, three, four, five, six, _hide=0 };

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, face f) {
        switch(f) {
            case face::one:   return os << "⚀";
            case face::two:   return os << "⚁";
            case face::three: return os << "⚂";
            case face::four:  return os << "⚃";
            case face::five:  return os << "⚄";
            case face::six:   return os << "⚅";
            case face::_hide: default: return os << ".";
        }
    }

    face roll_one() {
        static mt19937 e { random_device{}() };
        static uniform_int_distribution<Score> dist(Score(face::one), Score(face::six));
        return face{dist(e)};
    }
}

template <size_t... I>
struct hand_impl {
    static constexpr size_t N = sizeof...(I);
  private:
    static_assert(is_same_v<index_sequence<I...>, make_index_sequence<N> >, "this hack merely enables fold expressions");
    using dice_t      = array<face, N>;
    using selection_t = array<bool, N>;

    dice_t      faces;
    selection_t held = {};

  public:
    hand_impl() {
        generate_n(faces.begin(), N, roll_one);
    }

    void hold_highest() {
        held = matching(max({faces[I]...}));
    }

    void reroll() {
        faces = {{ (held[I]? faces[I] : roll_one())... }};
    }

    enum class method { upper_box, _3_of_a_kind, _4_of_a_kind, full_house,
                  small_straight, large_straight, yahtzee, chance };

    struct candidate_t { 
        dice_t faces;
        selection_t key;
        method how;
    };

    friend size_t score(candidate_t c) {
        // fixed
        switch(c.how) {
            case method::full_house:     return 25;
            case method::small_straight: return 30;
            case method::large_straight: return 40;
            case method::yahtzee:        return 50;
            default: break;
        }

        // depending on face values
        size_t all_values[] = { Score(c.faces[I])... };

        switch(c.how) {
            case method::upper_box:      return ((c.key[I]? all_values[I] : 0) + ...);
            case method::_3_of_a_kind: 
            case method::_4_of_a_kind: 
            case method::chance:         return (all_values[I] + ...);
            default: throw runtime_error("illegal move");
        }
    }

    auto generate() const {
        vector<candidate_t> result;

        result.push_back({ faces, all(), method::chance });

        // equal groups
        for (face f : {face::one, face::two, face::three, face::four, face::five, face::six}) {
            auto m = matching(f);
            auto n = cardinality(m);
            if (n) result.push_back({ faces, m, method::upper_box });
            if (n==5) result.push_back({ faces, m, method::yahtzee });
            if (n>=4) {
                if (n>4) *find(begin(m), end(m), true) = false; // discard one
                result.push_back({ faces, m, method::_4_of_a_kind });
            }
            if (n>=3) {
                if (n>3) *find(begin(m), end(m), true) = false; // discard one
                result.push_back({ faces, m, method::_3_of_a_kind });

                // look at remaining two
                dice_t other {{ (m[I]? face::_hide : faces[I])... }};
                sort(begin(other), end(other));
                // if they match, it's also a full house
                if (other[0] == other[1])
                    result.push_back({ faces, m, method::full_house });
            }
        }

        {
            // straights (increasing series)
            auto inorder = faces;
            sort(begin(inorder), end(inorder), greater<>{}); // favour the higher values

            auto decreasing_at = [&](size_t i) {
                return Score(inorder[i]) == 1 + Score(inorder[(i+1) % N])? 'y':'n';
            };

            char const s[] = { decreasing_at(I)... };
            if (auto where = string_view(s).find("yyyy"); where != string_view::npos)
                result.push_back({ inorder, selection_t { (I>=where && I<where+4)... }, method::large_straight });
            if (auto where = string_view(s).find("yyy"); where != string_view::npos)
                result.push_back({ inorder, selection_t { (I>=where && I<where+3)... }, method::small_straight });
        }

        return result;
    }

  private:
    static selection_t all() { return { (void(I), true)... }; }

    selection_t matching(face f) const {
        return { (faces[I] == f)... };
    }

    static size_t cardinality(selection_t s) {
        return count(begin(s), end(s), true);
    }

    template <size_t Index>
    static ostream& print_held(ostream& os, dice_t faces, selection_t held) {
        return os << faces[Index] << (held[Index]? "\xCC\xB2":"");
    }

    template <size_t Index>
    static ostream& print_key_dice(ostream& os, dice_t faces, selection_t key) {
        return os << (key[Index]? faces[Index] : face::_hide);
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, hand_impl h) {
        return (print_held<I>(os, h.faces, h.held), ...);
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, candidate_t const& c) {
        struct R { ostream& os; ios::fmtflags kept; ~R() { os.flags(kept); } } keep { os, os.flags() };

        os << "[" << left << setw(15) << c.how << "] ";
        return (print_key_dice<I>(os, c.faces, c.key), ...);
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, method m) {
        switch(m) {
            case method::upper_box:      return os << "upper box";
            case method::_3_of_a_kind:   return os << "three of a kind";
            case method::_4_of_a_kind:   return os << "four of a kind";
            case method::full_house:     return os << "full house";
            case method::small_straight: return os << "small straight";
            case method::large_straight: return os << "large straight";
            case method::yahtzee:        return os << "yahtzee";
            case method::chance:         return os << "chance";
        }
        return os << "[no score]";
    }
};

template <size_t... I> hand_impl<I...> make_hand_helper(index_sequence<I...>) { return {}; }
template <size_t N = 5> auto make_hand() { return make_hand_helper(make_index_sequence<N>{}); }

template <size_t N = 5> using hand = decltype(make_hand<N>());
using Yahtzee = hand<>;

int main() {

    Yahtzee hand = make_hand();
    auto rolls = 3;

    do {
        hand.hold_highest();
        cout << hand << "\n";

        multimap<Score, Yahtzee::candidate_t, greater<> > ranked;
        for (auto c : hand.generate())
            ranked.emplace(score(c), c);

        for (auto&& [score, c] : ranked)
            cout << setw(2) << score << " - " << c << "\n";

        hand.reroll();
    } while (--rolls);
}
```

Printing

```
⚁⚄⚅̲⚃⚂ ¹
40 - [large straight ] ⚅⚄⚃⚂.
30 - [small straight ] ⚅⚄⚃..
20 - [chance         ] ⚁⚄⚅⚃⚂
 6 - [upper box      ] ..⚅..
 5 - [upper box      ] .⚄...
 4 - [upper box      ] ...⚃.
 3 - [upper box      ] ....⚂
 2 - [upper box      ] ⚁....
⚃⚃⚅̲⚅̲⚁ ¹
22 - [chance         ] ⚃⚃⚅⚅⚁
12 - [upper box      ] ..⚅⚅.
 8 - [upper box      ] ⚃⚃...
 2 - [upper box      ] ....⚁
⚅̲⚅̲⚅̲⚅̲⚂ ¹
27 - [chance         ] ⚅⚅⚅⚅⚂
27 - [four of a kind ] ⚅⚅⚅⚅.
27 - [three of a kind] .⚅⚅⚅.
25 - [full house     ] .⚅⚅⚅.
24 - [upper box      ] ⚅⚅⚅⚅.
 3 - [upper box      ] ....⚂
```

---

¹ sadly browser don't all want to honour U+0332 COMBINING LOW LINE, which should underline the held dice, like so: [image]

Comment: fold expressions over a index sequence returned by `make_index_sequence` seem *slightly overkill*. I think this would be more understandable (although lengthier) if you used `std::transform` in those places

Comment: @Caleth I'm happy that after a few months someone finally notices this post. And yes, it is over the top, that was the point. I chose the fold expressions because it would potentially allow for constexpr evaluation functions :)

Comment: If you want over the top: [you could use](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com) an in-class initializer for `faces` using an immediately invoked lambda that calls `generate_n`, so you can get rid of the `hand_impl` constructor. Otherwise, very nice :)